# Calculating median on the spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark Dataframe and i want to calculate the median from the given data.

```
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("sql").setMaster("local"));
        SQLContext sql = new SQLContext(sc);
        //HiveContext

        DataFrame df =sql.read().json("test.json");
        df.registerTempTable("sample");
DataFrame df1=sql.sql("SELECT percentile_approx(imp_recall_timeinterval.average, 0.5) FROM sample");
```

but i am not getting the output.
I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function percentile_approx;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:65)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry.lookupFunction(FunctionRegistry.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5$$anonfun$applyOrElse$24.apply(Analyzer.scala:574)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5$$anonfun$applyOrElse$24.apply(Analyzer.scala:574)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$.withPosition(package.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:573)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:570)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:259)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:259)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:258)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionDown$1(QueryPlan.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:89)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:94)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsDown(QueryPlan.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$12.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:570)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$12.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:568)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$.apply(Analyzer.scala:568)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$.apply(Analyzer.scala:567)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
        at com.cloudera.sparkwordcount.JavaWordCount.<init>(JavaWordCount.java:41)
        at com.cloudera.sparkwordcount.JavaWordCount.main(JavaWordCount.java:131)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Please provide me the easiest way to calculate the median.
I tried many solutions that are available but unable to find the right one.
Note:- I am using spark 1.6.1 version.

Here is the complete code:-

JavaWordCount.java

```
package com.cloudera.sparkwordcount;

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
public class JavaWordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("sql").setMaster("local"));
        //SQLContext sql = new SQLContext(sc);
        HiveContext sql =new HiveContext(sc);
        DataFrame df =sql.read().json("test.json");
        df.registerTempTable("sample");
        DataFrame df2=sql.sql("SELECT percentile_approx(imp_recall_timeinterval.average, 0.5) FROM sample");
        System.out.println("Median is =======>");
        df2.show();
}
}
```

and here is pom.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Copyright (c) 2014, Cloudera, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

  Cloudera, Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
  Version 2.0 (the "License"). You may not use this file except in
  compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  This software is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
  CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for
  the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the
  License.
  -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.cloudera.sparkwrodcount</groupId>
  <artifactId>sparkwordcount</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>"Spark Word Count"</name>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>maven-hadoop</id>
      <name>Hadoop Releases</name>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>cloudera-repos</id>
      <name>Cloudera Repos</name>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>  
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

> The UDF "percentile_approx()" that you are using is available when you
>   use hive context instead of SQLContext. Try using HiveContext.

```
    SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("sql").setMaster("local"));
        //SQLContext sql = new SQLContext(sc);
        HiveContext sql = new HiveContext(sc);

        DataFrame df =sql.read().json("test.json");
        df.registerTempTable("sample");
DataFrame df1=sql.sql("SELECT percentile_approx(imp_recall_timeinterval.average, 0.5) FROM sample");
```

***Dont forget to import the required libraries for hive.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have added the following dependency in pom.xml       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>    .. but it does not show the HiveContext when i use it in my java class

Comment: thats not the right repo. use this one <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: I am getting the same exception. HiveContext has been imported but it is throwing same error at run time.

Comment: can you share the complete code. it would be easier to debug then. please mention the all the libraries and the respective versions also.

Comment: now i am getting the following exception:-         Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@58affbdf, see the next exception for details.

Comment: are you using the CDH version or HDP version.